# How does PHP's crypt function work internally?

Tags: php, hash, crypt

If I make the following call in PHP it will use my password and salt to hash it a number of times with sha512:

```
echo crypt('password', '$6$rounds=1000$salt');
```

However, I wonder how this process really works. Is it something like this?:

```
$hash = hash('sha512', 'password' . 'salt');
for ($i = 1; $i < 1000; $i++) {
    $hash = hash('sha512', $hash);
}
echo base64_encode($hash);
```

Or is it a really complex process?

The reason I'm asking is because I would like a cryptographic hashing system that is easy to implement in other languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for a strong password hashing algorithm to implement across different languages, use [bcrypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt). There are libs for Java, C#, JavaScript, PHP, obj-C, Python, Perl, etc.

If this is for a login form, a good idea is to use a JavaScript bcrypt lib, and have the hash transmitted to the server. This allows the work factor to be reasonably large without overloading your server or introducing a DoS vulnerability.

Comment: Oh, and use SSL. You can pick up certs for almost nothing (there are even free CAs now!) so there's no excuse for plaintext logins.

Comment: Hash injection. Hmm. Doesn't that defeat the original use of hashing somehow? If you pass the hash only and not the secret?

Comment: @hakra No, the client-side hash would be hashed *again* on the server, with a higher performance hash (e.g. SHA512). This gives you the performance benefit without making the hash the password.

Answer (score 3):

You can check out the actual crypt() source code here:

https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/crypt.c

That said, as others pointed out, you should probably be using bcrypt if you're hashing passwords. Here is a popular post about password hashing methodology:

http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/